# fpdf document printing only 1 page

Tags: php, fpdf

I am new to fpdf and not able to figure out what i am doing wrong in the following code.

I need to print two records per page.

First page is getting generated fine but no other pages are being generated.

May be i have a bug in my loop...pls help

alo pictures are not being printed when i am giving the variable like $pic[$i] but they are getting printed when i am typing the absolute path which is pictures/1.jpg. Although pictures are being printed in other documents with $pic[$i].

```
<?php
    session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
    $cr = $_POST['cour'];
    $s = $_POST['sem'];
    $title = $cr." ".$s." ".'2012-13';
    require('fpdf.php');
    include('../includes/connection.php');
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `student` WHERE AppliedCourse ='$cr'";
    $rs = mysql_query($sql) or die($sql. "<br/>".mysql_error());
    if(0 == mysql_num_rows($rs))
    {
        $_SESSION['db_error'] = "<h2><font color = 'RED'>No such course found! Pease select again.</font></h2>";
        header('Location: printAC.php');
    }
    else {

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs))
     {
            $formno[] = $row ['FormNo']; 
            $rno[] = $row ['rollno'];
            $snm[] = $row ['StudentNm'];          
            $fnm[] = $row ['FathersNm'];
            $mnm[] = $row ['MothersNm'];
            $addr[] = $row['Address'];
            $pic[] = $row['imagenm'];
            $comm[] = $row['SocialCat'];
     }
     $pdf = new FPDF('P','pt','A4');
     $pdf->SetFont('Times','B',16);
     $pdf->SetMargins(44.737,90.20,44.737);
     $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak('true',95);
     $i = 0;
     while($i < count($row))
     {

        $j = $i + 1;


            $pdf->AddPage();

             // Block 1

            $pdf->SetFont('Times','B',16);
            $pdf->SetXY(186.70,50.20);
            $pdf->Cell(204.16,30,$title,0,0,'C');

            // Block 1

            $pdf->Image('pictures/1.jpg',475.34,30.20,64.5,79);
            $pdf->Cell(165,260,' ',0,1,'');

            // Block 1

            $pdf->SetXY(55,80);
            $pdf->SetFont('Helvetica','',14);
            $pdf->Cell(60,20,'Roll No. : ',0,0,'L');
            $pdf->Cell(60,20,$rno[$i],0,0,'L');
            $pdf->Cell(70,20,'Form No. : ',0,0,'L');
            $pdf->Cell(60,20,$formno[$i],0,0,'L');
            $pdf->Cell(80,20,'Community : ',0,0,'L');
            $pdf->Cell(60,20,$comm[$i],0,1,'L');

            // Block 1  

            $pdf->SetXY(55,95);
            $pdf->Cell(55,20,'Name :',0,0,'L');
            $pdf->Cell(412,20,$snm[$i],0,1,'L');

            // Block 1

            $pdf->SetXY(55,115);
            $pdf->Cell(170,12,"Father's/Husband's Name :",0,0,'L');
            $pdf->Cell(323,12,$fnm[$i],0,1,'L');

            // Block 1

            $pdf->SetXY(55,130);
            $pdf->Cell(105,12,"Mother's Name :",0,0,'L');
            $pdf->Cell(372,12,$mnm[$i],0,1,'L');

            // Block 1

            $pdf->SetXY(55,145);
            $pdf->Cell(60,12,"Address :",0,0,'L');
            $pdf->Cell(165,60,$addr[$i],0,0,'');


            //****************************************//

            // Block 2

            $pdf->SetFont('Times','B',16);
            $pdf->SetXY(186.70,450.20);
            $pdf->Cell(204.16,30,$title,0,0,'C');

            // Block 2

            $pdf->Image('pictures/2.jpg',475.34,430.20,64.5,79);
            $pdf->Cell(165,260,' ',0,1,'');

            // Block 2

            $pdf->SetXY(55,480);
            $pdf->SetFont('Helvetica','',14);
            $pdf->Cell(60,20,'Roll No. : ',0,0,'L');
            $pdf->Cell(60,20,$rno[$j],0,0,'L');
            $pdf->Cell(70,20,'Form No. : ',0,0,'L');
            $pdf->Cell(60,20,$formno[$j],0,0,'L');
            $pdf->Cell(80,20,'Community : ',0,0,'L');
            $pdf->Cell(60,20,$comm[$j],0,1,'L');

            // Block 2  

            $pdf->SetXY(55,493);
            $pdf->Cell(55,20,'Name :',0,0,'L');
            $pdf->Cell(412,20,$snm[$j],0,1,'L');

            // Block 2

            $pdf->SetXY(55,510);
            $pdf->Cell(170,12,"Father's/Husband's Name :",0,0,'L');
            $pdf->Cell(323,12,$fnm[$j],0,1,'L');

            // Block 2

            $pdf->SetXY(55,525);
            $pdf->Cell(105,12,"Mother's Name :",0,0,'L');
            $pdf->Cell(372,12,$mnm[$j],0,1,'L');

            // Block 2

            $pdf->SetXY(55,540);
            $pdf->Cell(60,12,"Address :",0,0,'L');
            $pdf->Cell(165,60,$addr[$j],0,0,'');

            $i++;

        }

             $pdf->Output();
    }
    mysql_close($con);
}
?>
```

Comment: **Heads up!** Future versions of PHP are *deprecating and removing* the `mysql_` family of functions. Now would be a great time to [switch to PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo) or [mysqli](http://php.net/book.mysqli).

Comment: are u getting the desired first page